# Intermittent failure of dependencyCheck on Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, jenkins-plugins, owasp

We are using the owasp dependencyCheck plugin in our project. 
Version used: 1.4.5

We are facing the following issue in our build jobs on Jenkins:

The build job fails intermittently saying " :dependencyCheck FAILED "

> The stacktrace of the error is as follows:
>
> :dependencyCheck
>
> Verifying dependencies for project stock-service
>
> Checking for updates and analyzing vulnerabilities for dependencies
>
> Unable to update Cached Web DataSource, using local data instead. Results may not include recent vulnerabilities.
>
> Exception occurred initializing CPE Analyzer.
>
> Generating report for project stock-service
>
> Found 0 vulnerabilities in project stock-service
>     :dependencyCheck FAILED
>
> Caused by: org.owasp.dependencycheck.exception.ExceptionCollection: One or more exceptions occurred during dependency-check analysis
>       org.xml.sax.SAXException: Unable to get primary key for new cpe: cpe:/a:uchida_yoko_co._ltd:assetbase:8.0
>
> org.owasp.dependencycheck.data.nvdcve.DatabaseException: Unable to get primary key for new cpe: cpe:/a:uchida_yoko_co._ltd:assetbase:8.0
>       An exception occurred accessing the database
>       at org.owasp.dependencycheck.Engine.analyzeDependencies(Engine.java:543)
>       at org.owasp.dependencycheck.Engine$analyzeDependencies$0.call(Unknown Source)
>       at org.owasp.dependencycheck.gradle.tasks.Check.check(Check.groovy:86) 
>       ... 66 more

Answer (score 0):

If your code has multiple microservices, then all the services create a database locally on Jenkins and update it as part of owasp dependencyCheck task on the following location:

> /{your jenkins
>   directory}/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.owasp/dependency-check-utils/dependency-check-data/3.0/dc.h2.db

Since this file is shared by all the services, there are locking issues. If any one service fails during build, the lock that it created on the file is not removed and thus the other services would subsequently fail.
Following link describes the issue and suggests a solution:

> https://github.com/jeremylong/DependencyCheck/issues/410

This solution was not usable as is, we had to change the "autoUpdate=true" so that the service creates a db file if it does not already exist.
After the above change ( i.e adding "data directory" configuration in dependencyCheck task [visit the above link for this config]),
the issue seems to have been fixed.